# Random function in Python

Tags: python, function, random

How can I use the random function (in Python) to choose a string from a txt list?

---

i want random from a list :

```
import random
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
f = open(filename)
f.close()
print  random.choice(f)
```

is this code ok ?

Comment: At least pretend to look at the so very, very nice documentation before asking a question...

Comment: You might edit the title or expand upon your question.  As written there is no mention of any specific problem with the random function itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
> import random
> list_of_strings = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
> randomly_chosen_string = random.choice(list_of_strings)
> help(random.choice)
Help on method choice in module random:

choice(self, seq) method of random.Random instance
Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

file = open("file.txt", "r")
list = file.readlines()
def getline ():
    return list[random.randint(0,(len(list) - 1))]

getline()
```

Comment: assuming that file.txt contains sonething like
aaa
bbb
ccc
etc...
(one word per line)
then that will work

Comment: +1 for brevity, and welcome to SO! But please don't use `list` for a variable name, as `list()` is a function name in Python. Also, you should look into the `with` statements for file reading. :]

Comment: sorry, don't know much Python and this was the first thing to come into my head and BTW, I figured common lisp doesn't choke on there being a variable AND a function named list, so why should Python